# Antipodal Land Area Calculation

Tags: geography, recreational-mathematics, version-12

Mathematica 12 does antipodal graphics! See [here](http://gladhoboexpress.blogspot.com/2019/04/antipodal-new-zealand.html) for my treatment of antipodal New Zealand. Most of the Earth's above-sea-level land will have ocean at its antipode. Is there a way to calculate what percentage of above-sea-level land will also have above-sea-level land at its antipode?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Yes, this is possible with a little faff.

What we want to do is get the `RegionUnion` of all the countries the antipode intersects with, and then intersect the antipode with that region, and get the remaining area.

Let's use New Zealand as an example.

```
ant = GeoAntipode[Polygon@Entity["Country", "NewZealand"]]
```

[image]

Now, we can get the countries that this antipode intersects using `GeoEntities`:

```
GeoEntities[ant, "Country"]
```

> `{Entity["Country", "Portugal"], Entity["Country", "Spain"], 
>    Entity["Country", "Gibraltar"], Entity["Country", "Morocco"]}`

Now, it seems like there's a bit of a bug with Gibraltar in my solution, so I've removed it. I'm not sure what causes it, but including Gibraltar deletes Morocco from the Region (don't tell the British).

```
countries = 
 RegionUnion @@ (EntityValue[{Entity["Country", "Portugal"], 
      Entity["Country", "Spain"], Entity["Country", "Morocco"]}, 
     "Polygon"] /. GeoPosition[x_] -> x)
```

(We need to do `GeoPosition[x_]->x` to convert the GeoPositions into regular points, for `Region` calculations)

Now we intersect our antipode with this region:

```
int = RegionIntersection[ant /. GeoPosition[x_] -> x, countries]
```

(This can take a little time depending on the complexity of your polygons)

We can now convert back to GeoPositions:

```
geoint = MeshPrimitives[int, 2] /. Polygon[x_] -> Polygon[GeoPosition[x]]
```

and check the graphics to make sure we got it right:

```
GeoGraphics[geoint]
```

[image]

Finally, to get the actual area of intersections:

```
GeoArea[geoint] // Total
```

> `Quantity[1.58773*10^11, ("Meters")^2]`

We can see that we are in the right ballpark:

```
UnitConvert[GeoArea[Entity["Country", "NewZealand"]]]
```

> `Quantity[2.64511*10^11, ("Meters")^2]`