# How to display an intersection of two geo regions?

Tags: geographics, intersection

```
GeoGraphics[{
    {
        GeoStyling["StreetMap"],
        First[GeoNearest["Country",geoPosition]]["Polygon"],GeoDisk[geoPosition,Quantity[300,"Miles"]]
    }
        GeoMarker[geoPosition]
},GeoBackground->None]
```

Suppose I evaluate the above expression with

```
geoPosition = GeoPosition[{35.6762`,139.6503`}]
```

It plots the background with a union of country's polygon and disk's polygon but I want intersection of the two. How to do this?

Comment: I have more-or-less done this in [this answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/195594/57593). I simply used `RegionIntersection` after making `Regions` from the polygons.

Comment: @CarlLange do you know how to get polygon structure for the `GeoDisk[geoPosition,Quantity[300,"Miles"]]`?

Comment: Easiest thing to do is generate a number of points equidistant from the centre and create a polygon from that. I'll add an answer in a moment.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

We can do this fairly easily by converting our geographic regions into `Region`s and using `RegionIntersection`.

First let's get our geographic regions.

```
centre = GeoPosition[{35.6762`, 139.6503`}]

p1 = First[GeoNearest["Country", centre]]["Polygon"]
```

Now, it's not easy to use `GeoDisk` directly for our calculation, so we'll regenerate this by creating a `Polygon` with a list of points equidistant from the centre.

```
radius = Quantity[300, "Miles"]

p2 = Polygon[
  Table[GeoDestination[centre, GeoDisplacement[{radius, b}]], {b, 0, 360, 
    1}]]
```

Now we will double-check that this looks right:

```
GeoGraphics[{p1, p2}]
```

[image]

Now we compute the intersection by turning the polygons into regions and taking RegionIntersection of that.

```
r1 = Region[p1 /. GeoPosition[x___] -> x]

r2 = Region[p2 /. GeoPosition[x___] -> x]

int = RegionIntersection[r1, r2, PerformanceGoal -> "Speed"]
```

[image]

Now we can turn this back into a geo polygon:

```
geoint = int /. Region[Polygon[x_]] -> Polygon[GeoPosition[x]]
```

And there we are:

```
GeoGraphics[{geoint}]
```

[image]

Now we can do things like `GeoArea` easily with `GeoArea[geoint]` (in this case, 178393km^2!)

Note that Sato island is not included - you may need to use `GeoVariant[..., "AllAreas"]` to get every extended part of a country. It may return `FilledCurve`s which may be harder to turn into `Region`s.

Comment: One more question, doesn't `RegionIntersection` also return a polygon object if the inputs are polygon? What is the purpose of `MeshPrimitives[BoundaryDiscretizeRegion[...], 2]`?

Comment: Indeed, thank you, I have edited my answer. That was a holdover from some previous code I used as the base of this answer.

Comment: Sorry I am wrong `RegionIntersection` returns `MeshRegion` in the case of polygon inputs so I think `MeshPrimitives[..., 2]` is necessary to get 2D-polygons.